# Counting ways to reach 30 with the sum of 3 numbers in the interval [0,30]

Tags: combinatorics

I need help counting how many ways there are of getting $30$ with the sum of $3$ natural numbers between $0$ and $30$.

The numbers can be repeated and order does matter. This means that $28 + 2 + 0$ is a different solution from $2 + 0 + 28$.

I have no idea where to start, so any clue would be really helpful!

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also, for clarity:  does order matter?  That is, are $1+2+27$ and $27+1+2$ the same solution?

Comment: @lulu order does not matter. 1 + 2 + 27 is not the same as 27 + 1 + 2

Comment: What do you mean?  If those solutions are different then order *does* matter.

Comment: The first number can be anywhere between $0$ and $30$ (inclusive).  The second number can be anywhere between $0$ and $(30-x).$  The 3rd number is forced.  You just have to count the number of possibilities for the first two numbers.

Comment: Thanks @DougM !!

Comment: Note that @DougM 's comment only works if order matters, that is, $1+2+27$ is not the same as $2+1+27$.

Comment: Unless I have misinterpreted the posting, this is a $\color{red}{\text{Stars and Bars}}$ problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see 
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).